# How to pass data from container activity to its child fragments in android?

Tags: android

This is my container activity `Table_info` and I want to pass the data from container activity to its child fragment `Table_no`. But I am receiving the string in fragment as `null`.

**Code for Table_info:**

```
package com.example.androiddbconnection;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class Table_info extends FragmentActivity {
String restaurant;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tableinfo_frag);

Intent in=getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    restaurant = bundle.getString("outletname");
    Log.d("in mainactivity",restaurant);

  Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();

  bundle1.putString("restaurant",restaurant);

    Table_no fragment=new Table_no();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle1);



    }


  }
```

This is my fragment **Table_no**:

```
public class Table_no extends Fragment {

String restaurant12;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 
        if (bundle == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"argum is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
            else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"argume", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        restaurant12=bundle.toString();
        Log.d("arguments", restaurant12);
        }

 }
```

But I am getting the response as `'argum is null'`

Comment: post the code where you are loading the fragment with FragmentTransaction.

Comment: i am not loading the fragment with fragment transaction. i am loading the fragment onclick of button of another fragment

Comment: how are you doing it then?

Comment: I found the solution. the issue was due to the support library. and yes @rachit I had to use fragmentTransaction

Answer (score 1):

In order to call Fragment's methods from the Activity you need to add your activity to the `FragmentTransaction` then you can do like that:

on the Activity's site:

```
Table_no mTable_no = (Table_no) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Table_no_tag");
mTable_no.setMyData(String);
```

on the Fragment's site:

```
 public void setMyData(String string) {
    this.string = string;
 }
```

Comment: another good way is to have a common interface for all the fragments as well.
good solution btw.

Comment: i am not calling any fragment method from activity. setArguments is the buildin method

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor for fragment. you can directly pass values to fragment using it's constructor.

```
public class Table_no extends Fragment {

String restaurant12="";

public Table_no(String restaurant)
{
restaurant12=restaurant;
}

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),restaurant12, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
```

Comment: it gives me logcat error Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.androiddbconnection.Table_no

Answer (score 0):

Even I am facing the same issue but adding below line solved my problem.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
       String getFeatureDescription= bundle.getString("desc");

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        b.putString("bb",getFeatureDescription);

        FragmentFeatureOverview ff = new FragmentFeatureOverview();
        ff.setArguments(b );
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,ff).commit();
```

But after adding this line my tabs stops swapping.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace (R.id.fragmentContainer,ff).commit();
```